# php memory exhaust issue when counting unique emails from multiple arrays.

Tags: php

```
<?php
$array1 =   array(
        'abc@example.com'=>array('name'=>'username','ip'=>'127.0.0.1'),
        'xyz@example.com'=>array('name'=>'username','ip'=>'127.0.0.1')
        );

$array2 =   array(
        'lmn@example.com'=>array('name'=>'username','ip'=>'127.0.0.1'),
        'pqr@example.com'=>array('name'=>'username','ip'=>'127.0.0.1')
        );

$array3 =   array(
        'pqr@example.com'=>array('name'=>'username','ip'=>'127.0.0.1'),
        'abc@example.com'=>array('name'=>'username','ip'=>'127.0.0.1')
        );

$array4 =   array(
        'xyz@example.com'=>array('name'=>'username','ip'=>'127.0.0.1'),
        'pqr@example.com'=>array('name'=>'username','ip'=>'127.0.0.1')
        );  

$final_arr = array();

$final_arr = array_merge($array1,$array2,$array3,$array4);          

echo count($final_arr);

?>
```

This is the example code in this i have 4 array with 2 elements in each array.
and i am using array_merge() function to get unique emails in all array.

but in this way i am increasing size of final array variable until all array not getting merge into final array but this is giving me proper result unique emails count from all arrays.

In case if i use 50 array and size of each array have 50k elements.

and if i merge all array in single variable this will create memory exhaust error in php because large variable size.

is there any possible way to count unique emails from all array by some comparison to overcome memory exhaust issue.

Comment: And why do you need to merge arrays?

Comment: each array have a email_id as key and multiple array could repeat same email_id to count unique emails from all array if merge multiple array will not repeat same key and can able to count unique emails from final list.@u_mulder

Comment: If you need to count unique emails - then count them. Why do you need to merge?

Comment: if you have 4 array and each array have 2 element and if count this will always return 8 but i need unique count so need to merge and then those repeating will be count only once.@u_mulder

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how your arrays are stored and where you take them. But if you need to **count** unique emails - then **count** unique emails, don't **merge** arrays.

```
$array1 =   array(
        'abc@example.com'=>array('name'=>'username','ip'=>'127.0.0.1'),
        'xyz@example.com'=>array('name'=>'username','ip'=>'127.0.0.1')
        );

$array2 =   array(
        'lmn@example.com'=>array('name'=>'username','ip'=>'127.0.0.1'),
        'pqr@example.com'=>array('name'=>'username','ip'=>'127.0.0.1')
        );

$array3 =   array(
        'pqr@example.com'=>array('name'=>'username','ip'=>'127.0.0.1'),
        'abc@example.com'=>array('name'=>'username','ip'=>'127.0.0.1')
        );

$array4 =   array(
        'xyz@example.com'=>array('name'=>'username','ip'=>'127.0.0.1'),
        'pqr@example.com'=>array('name'=>'username','ip'=>'127.0.0.1')
        );  

$unique_emails = array();

foreach ($array1 as $email => $v) {
    if (!isset($unique_emails[$email])) {
        $unique_emails[$email] = 1;
    } else {
        $unique_emails[$email]++;
    }
}

foreach ($array2 as $email => $v) {
    if (!isset($unique_emails[$email])) {
        $unique_emails[$email] = 1;
    } else {
        $unique_emails[$email]++;
    }
}

// for third and forth arrays the same.
print_r($unique_emails);
// outputs Array ( [abc@example.com] => 2 [xyz@example.com] => 2 [lmn@example.com] => 1 [pqr@example.com] => 3 )
```

Comment: Oh dear.. I didn't catch the word "count" in the original post. +1 for a smarter solution.

Comment: Thanks for adding this solution this will definitely use less memory because you have only counter in value part while array_merge() returns full value which is consuming more memory but in this case also same problem occur because $unique_emails array size will increase until all array not processed.

Answer (score 1):

If this were me, I'd probably use a hash as an associative array key, like so:

```
<?php
$uniqueEmailInfos=Array();
foreach($emailInfos as $emailInfo){
 $key=Sha1(Json_Encode($emailInfo));
 $uniqueEmailInfos[$key]=$emailInfo;
}
?>
```

You could even try to save more memory by unsetting the source as you go along:

```
<?php
$uniqueEmailInfos=Array();
foreach($emailInfos as $emailInfo_key=>$emailInfo_value){
 $key=Sha1(Json_Encode($emailInfo_value));
 $uniqueEmailInfos[$key]=$emailInfo_value;
 unset($emailInfos[$emailInfo_key]);
}
?>
```

When the loop is done, $uniqueEmailInfos should contain only unique email entries. This would probably be very inefficient, though.

If your loop is already fast/good, and your only problem is memory, I would instead suggest possibly altering the "memory_limit" setting of php.ini instead.

Comment: but in this also can't able to control size of $uniqueEmailInfos array until all elements not store in this array once.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but in the second code snippet, $emailInfos gets smaller as you go through the loop, which helps to minimize memory usage.

Comment: I am trying to control size of $uniqueEmailInfos this because it's going to larger till not add all elements at least once.

Comment: Does your original code show all data being stored in an email info array? If your production code contains much more data, you can save a bit more space by storing the $emailInfo_key field as the value as well. Otherwise, that Sha1() hash is probably longer than just an email+username+ip

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

It removes the memory limit from PHP hence you won't run out of memory - altough it would be more usefull to take totally different approach to your data, because the fact you run out of memory simply means it's not effective.

Comment: But it might be actually better tu have all the data in database and perform some advanced mysql query.

Comment: Could you tell me if i have json array in database and i have to perform same operation to count unique emails from multiple row of json how to do it ?

Comment: Okay, I've added the explanation why I've suggested this.